# Change <img> src Attribute with spaces in name

Tags: javascript, src, spaces

This seems like it should be simple, but it's proving to be a pain.  How do you set the src of an image to a name containing spaces?  I tried this way:

```
var newSrc = "images/" + sname[field].split(":")[selected] + ".png";
document.getElementById("image" + field).src = newSrc;
```

as well as putting the calculation directly into the space occupied by the newSrc variable.  However, the image never displays despite it being displayed on another element, and retrieval via

> document.getElementById("image" + field).src

shows it's in fact been set as

```
http://localhost/SkillPlanner/images/Branch%202.png
```

Technically, I guess there's two questions:

1) Why is it fully qualifying it when all I need is a relative link?

2) How can I keep the spaces intact as they are part of the filename?

Comment: Found a solution by doing the dumbest thing I could think of, which was to wrap the entire string I was adding in "unescape()".  Still don't know why it worked, but it did :P  Have to wait 5 hours to answer the question so I can add the answer and mark it solved :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As promissed (if a bit delayed), the solution was to wrap the string in "unescape", which forces thing like spaces to NOT be interpreted when used.

```
var newSrc = unescape("images/" + sname[field].split(":")[selected] + ".png");
```